# How can I update or insert a where by looking to see the data already exists in 2 of the columns?

Tags: postgresql, upsert, asyncpg

**My table is look like below:**

```
   id | u_id | server_id | user_id | pts | level | count | timestamp
```

I want to check when inserting new data or updating data if the values from data to be inserted already exist in both the `server_id` or `user_id` column. In other words, no two rows can have the same `server_id` or `user_id`.

Comment: Can you make those columns have unique properties? Also, can you include the table definition so we have a better idea of the table you are dealing with?

Comment: @rikola Table description is levelling system. Each user is part of a server, and they can be inside multiple servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an unique constraint to the table

```
alter table tablename add constraint ids_unique unique (server_id, user_id);
```

and then handle possible exceptions.

Comment: sorry but what you mean by `and then handle possible exceptions.`?

Comment: I mean that inserts that violate the rule will fail and generate an error/exception.

Comment: when i write the query for on_conflict which column must i specify then? nvm i managed to fix it i did `ON_CONFLICT(server_id, user_id)`